# Dynamically call php object property

Tags: php, object

In the php 7 docs, there's http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect. 
I'm trying to use this to call property dynamically. This code only prints `v1`. I want it to print `v1pqrxyz`

How can I do that? I'm using PHP version 7.0

```
class test{

    public $v1 = "v1";

    public function f1($a){
        return $a;
    }

    public function f2($b){
        return $b;
    }
}

$test1 = new test();

$arr = ['v1', 'f1("pqr")', 'f2("xyz")'];

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $test1->{$value};
}
```

Comment: You would need `eval` or regular expressions to handle string expressions like `'f1("pqr")'`. Both are unsafe and/or error prone. You should not do it. Whenever possible use `['v1', ['f1', ['arg1', 'arg2']], 'v2']` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible the way you constructed it, even if it looks promising. But, you could do the following for methods

```
$arr = [
   ['f1', ['pqr']],
   ['f2', ['xyz']],
   # or some multi argument function
   #['f3', ['a', 'b']],
];

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    list($method, $args) = $value;
    echo $test1->$method(...$args);
}
```

and members could be accessed like this

```
$arr = [
   'v1'
];

foreach ($arr as $member) {
    echo $test1->$member;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `call_user_func()`

```
 foreach ($arr as $value) {
   echo call_user_func([$test1,$value]);
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting error when doing it this way `Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'test' does not have a method 'f1()'`